# C#. Selenium. Regex in Find Element

Tags: c#, regex, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to use regexes or some "contain" function in `WebDriver.FindElement()`?

e.g. I have an element with XPath like this

```
//html//body//form//table//tbody//tr//td//a[@href='view.php?id=']
```

and `id` is a random number like `view.php?id=132548`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use XPath's contain function

```
//html//body//form//table//tbody//tr//td//a[contains(@href,'view.php?id=')]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions in [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/),

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("E[foo^='bar']"));  

E[foo="bar"]    an E element whose "foo" attribute value is exactly equal to "bar"
E[foo~="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value is a list of whitespace-separated values, one of which is exactly equal to "bar"
E[foo^="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value begins exactly with the string "bar"   
E[foo$="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value ends exactly with the string "bar" 
E[foo*="bar"]   an E element whose "foo" attribute value contains the substring "bar"
```

Comment: +1, but those are not regular expressions.  While it's obviously influenced by regex, that syntax belongs to CSS alone.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think regular expression is not suported in Selenium 2